# AngularJS :: Not working

Tags: angularjs

Please see below code. I am not able to understand why this is not working.

Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentController" ng-init="countries=[{name:'India',language:'Hindi'},{name:'United States',language:'English'}]">

    <div>

        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname">
        Student Name {{student.fullname()}}!!
    </div>

    <script>
        function studentController($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
                firstname: "Fname",
                lastname: "Lname",
                fullname: function () {
                    var studObj;
                    studObj = $scope.student;
                    return studObj.firstname + ' ' + studObj.lastname;
                }
            };

        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expression {{student.fullname()}} comes as it is in browser.

Thank you all!! However, see very similar code below - which is working. I am struggling to get the difference.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentController" ng-init="countries=[{name:'India',language:'Hindi'},{name:'United States',language:'English'}]">

    <div>

        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname">
        Student Name {{student.fullname()}}!!
    </div>

    <script>
        function studentController($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
                firstname: "Fname",
                lastname: "Lname",
                fullname: function () {
                    var studObj;
                    studObj = $scope.student;
                    return studObj.firstname + ' ' + studObj.lastname;
                }
            };

        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please follow any non-outdated tutorial to see what a simple Angular application should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your `myapp` first before using it. Also, your angular code should come after you've loaded the angularjs file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="studentController" ng-init="countries=[{name:'India',language:'Hindi'},{name:'United States',language:'English'}]">

    <div>

        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname">
        Student Name {{student.fullname()}}!!
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller("studentController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
                firstname: "Fname",
                lastname: "Lname",
                fullname: function () {
                    var studObj;
                    studObj = $scope.student;
                    return studObj.firstname + ' ' + studObj.lastname;
                }
            };

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You need to bring in Angular before your application code.
2. You need to register your controller with Angular's IoC container.

I made one change for the sake of style, `studentController` became `StudentController`. This is because controllers in Angular are new-able classes or constructor functions. Idiomatic JavaScript contsructor functions should be PascalCase.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="StudentController" ng-init="countries=[{name:'India',language:'Hindi'},{name:'United States',language:'English'}]">

    <div>

        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname">
        Student Name {{student.fullname()}}!!
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        StudentController.$inject = ['$scope'];
        function StudentController($scope) {
            $scope.student = {
                firstname: "Fname",
                lastname: "Lname",
                fullname: function () {
                    var studObj;
                    studObj = $scope.student;
                    return studObj.firstname + ' ' + studObj.lastname;
                }
            };
        }
      
        angular.module('myapp', []).controller('StudentController', StudentController);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script file and also remove myapp from ng-app, use your code in this way:-

```
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController" ng-init="countries=[{name:'India',language:'Hindi'},{name:'United States',language:'English'}]">

    <div>

        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.firstname">
        Student Name {{student.fullname()}}!!
    </div>

    <script>
        function studentController($scope) {
          $scope.student = {
                firstname: "Fname",
                lastname: "Lname",
                fullname: function () {
                    var studObj;
                    studObj = $scope.student;
                    return studObj.firstname + ' ' + studObj.lastname;
                }
            };

        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more details.